# Click dynamically created buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, button, view

I'm using MVC and in my View, I'm dynamically generating content using a For loop. Within each loop, I insert a "See comments" button.

If I click the first "See comments" button, how do I get it to execute code that is relevant to the data in the first block (e.g., Dish Detergent info)? E.g., how do I grab the ID from the model for that row of data since the buttons are dynamically generated?

I would like to use below jQuery code. But I don't see how to grab that particular row's ID.

```
 $("#seeComments").click(function () {
        alert(ID);
    });
```

[image: Dynamic button generation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are generating the html for each item, add data attributes to the button containing the values you are not displaying so they can be retrieved in the click event. Note use a class name for the button (not an ID attribute) since you will have duplicate ID which is invalid html.

For example

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <div class="answer"> // wrapper to allow selection
    <div class="heading">
      <span class="name">@Model[i].Name</span>
      <span class="rating">@Model[i].Rating</span>
    </div>
    .....
    <button class="comments" type=button" data-id="@Model[i].ID">See Comments</button>
    .....      
  </div> 
}
```

and the script

```
$('.comments').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var rating = $(this).closest('.answer').find('.rating').text();
  ....
}
```

Comment: Nice, works. But had to change @Model[i] to @Model.ElementAt(i) because can't use index on IEnumerable. And thank you for the extra script info. Had to look up 'closest' but understand it now. Works beautiful ... ;-)

Comment: Then you dont need a `for` loop (as you indicated in your question). If its `IEnumerable`, you can use a `foreach` loop e.g. `foreach(var item in Model) { ...` and use `@item.Name`

Comment: Originally, I was using foreach. However, I needed to count because I want to display up to the first 5 items in a highlighted section, then another loop to display the rest in another section. Is there a way to do a count using foreach? That's why I switched to the For loop. Thanks again, learning bit by bit ...

Comment: Only if you declare a counter outside the loop an increment it inside `int index = 0; foreach(var item in Model) {....; index++;}`. But either way will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the ID of the relevant row in the `data-id` attribute of the button and set `seeComments` as the `class` of the button. You didn't include your model class definition, so assuming it's an `IEnumerable`, your view code would be like this

```
@foreach (var answer in Model)
{
    .....


    <button type="button" data-id="@answer.ID" class="seeComments">See comments</button>
}
```

or like below if your model class contains a nested `IEnumerable` property named `Answers`

```
@foreach (var answer in Model.Answers)
{
    .....


    <button type="button" data-id="@answer.ID" class="seeComments">See comments</button>
}
```

then bind the click event for all `See Comments` buttons using `.seeComments` selector and use `.data("id")` to grab the id like below

```
$(".seeComments").click(function () {
    // this will display the data-id value of the clicked button
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```